# Alps Touchpad not working on VAIO VPCEH laptop

Tags: touchpad, vaio, alps

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a Sony Vaio(Edit: known from the tags). Although the touchpad is recognized, I am unable to lock the touchpad.

Answer (score 0):

you may try installing the package I've extraced from dell standard ubuntu image check this out https://askubuntu.com/a/278133/65801