# 'Disable Touchpad' Keyboard Shortcut doesn't work

Tags: 12.10, dell, touchpad, inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 5110 laptop. When I press the keyboard shortcut to disable the touchpad (`Fn+F3`) it shows this in the corner of the screen:

[image: Pointless notification]

But it does not actually disable the touchpad. This works perfectly on Windows. In fact, other than the notification, it doesn't seem to do **anything**: The light on the touchpad doesn't come on (it lights up when the touchpad's off under Windows) and the notification always shows the same image, like the computer doesn't even know it's supposed to be disabled. Is there a way to make this work right?

Update: I followed the instructions on getting hardware details & couldn't find anything that looked relevant. Here are the contents of [/var/log/dmesg](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/20042439/dmesg) and [/var/log/udev](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/20042439/udev); I didn't know what to look for in them.

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then **edit** your question adding the information.

Comment: Use this solution: http://askubuntu.com/a/211755/15943, Inspiron 17r has the same problem out-of-the-box with Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, but that worked. It also enabled multi-touch scrolling. Thanks!