# How to install touch pad driver on inspiron 7220 se?

Tags: 12.10, dell, touchpad, inspiron

I am trying to install this driver: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/606238/comments/202

My command line:

```
augre@augre-Inspiron-7720:~/Downloads/usr/src/psmouse-alps-1.3$ bash alps.sh

Usage: alps.sh func [func]+
  Valid funcs:
    a_parseargs
    a_usage
    dkms_bld_kc
    dkms_build_alps
    dkms_install_cp
    dkms_install_symlink
    dkms_pkg_tarball
    git
    qemu_add_driver
    qemu_clean_and_config
    qemu_create
    qemu_grow_img
    qemu_make
    qemu_mon
    qemu_run
    qemu_update_bios
    run_alps_debug
    run_dsdt_get
    run_tp_check
    run_tp_diags
    run_tune_alps
```

What can I do to fix this?

I have tried to build it, but get the following error:

```
augre@augre-Inspiron-7720:~/Downloads/usr/src/psmouse-alps-1.3$ sudo bash alps.sh dkms_build_alps
Must run dkms_install_cp or dkms_install_symlink before this
/usr/src/psmouse-alps-1.3/dkms.conf must have PACKAGE_VERSION set to alps-1.3
sudo: dkms: command not found
/usr/src/psmouse-alps-1.3/dkms.conf must have PACKAGE_VERSION set to alps-1.3
This places the psmouse.ko dlkm in /lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/updates/dkms
sudo: dkms: command not found
Build failed
cat: /var/lib/dkms/psmouse/alps-1.3/build/make.log: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Dell 7720 SE too and [I used this](http://www.askubuntu.com/questions/154770/alps-touchpad-on-dell-how-do-i-install-the-dkms-driver-to-enable-multitouch/211755#211755)

Fn+F3 and configuration works perfectly