# After upgrade to 14.10 touchpad freezes after a while

Tags: upgrade, mouse, touchpad

After upgrading to 14.10 my touchpad has some problems. After I've been using it for a while it freezes randomly. Before I have some output in `/dev/input/mice` after freezing no output at all. It seems to happen only when I'm using Unity; with GNOME I have no problem so far.

I don't know where to start digging. Any idea?

Comment: are you using any kind of power saving software ?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the guilty package.

My laptop is a Dell Latitude E6330 which has a 12.04 ubuntu preinstalled that I kept updgrading periodically until 14.10 (until the touchpad started freezing).

The `xinput --list` relevant output was

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer            id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ GlidePoint Virtual Touchpad           id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
```

I just solved the problem thanks to the answer to this post [How to configure glidepoint driver for touchpad?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282931/how-to-configure-glidepoint-driver-for-touchpad). I just uninstalled the `glidepoint` package which, I assume, comes from dell specific repositories http://dell.archive.canonical.com/ which only provides support for LTS versions.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove glidepoint
```

After that the touchpad didn't freeze again.

To make sure this kind of problems will not appear again I made a clean install to avoid using packages that might not been updated when upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

This [screen freeze while using touchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-prime/+bug/1220426) might be related to your issue. Recently (post #171) a patch was submitted to fix a race condition in x server. It should eventually be published through the usual update mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

These commands always work for me

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

they remove mouse driver then reload it