# Dell Inspiron 7720 - upgrade from 12.10 to 13.04 broke touchpad driver

Tags: dell, touchpad, 13.04, inspiron, alps

Today the updated informed me that there are udpates and a new version of Kubuntu. After installing the updates and pressing "Quit" the updater began upgrading to 13.04 (?!?!?!).
Anyway, after the upgrade the touchpad is not working any more.

```
I tried to install driver for touchpad using suggestions from this forum and ended up with this error during DKMS install:
DKMS make.log for psmouse-alps-dst-0.4 for kernel 3.8.0-19-generic (x86_64)
пт апр 26 11:10:50 EEST 2013
make: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic'
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/psmouse/alps-dst-0.4/build/src/psmouse-base.o
/var/lib/dkms/psmouse/alps-dst-0.4/build/src/psmouse-base.c: In function ‘__check_smartscroll’:
/var/lib/dkms/psmouse/alps-dst-0.4/build/src/psmouse-base.c:64:1: warning: return from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/psmouse/alps-dst-0.4/build/src/synaptics.o
/var/lib/dkms/psmouse/alps-dst-0.4/build/src/synaptics.c: In function ‘set_input_params’:
/var/lib/dkms/psmouse/alps-dst-0.4/build/src/synaptics.c:1153:3: error: too few arguments to function ‘input_mt_init_slots’
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/psmouse/alps-dst-0.4/build/src/synaptics.c:29:0:
include/linux/input/mt.h:78:5: note: declared here
/var/lib/dkms/psmouse/alps-dst-0.4/build/src/synaptics.c:1165:3: error: too few arguments to function ‘input_mt_init_slots’
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/psmouse/alps-dst-0.4/build/src/synaptics.c:29:0:
include/linux/input/mt.h:78:5: note: declared here
make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/psmouse/alps-dst-0.4/build/src/synaptics.o] Error 1
make: *** [psmouse.ko] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic'
```

I also came upon [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279375/support-for-alps-touchpad-ubuntu-13-04) topic and found it was closed (so not very useful)...

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: 'make'? Didn't you just try `sudo apt-get install dkms` in Terminal?

In any case, a duplicate is here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/279375/support-for-alps-touchpad-ubuntu-13-04?lq=1 and it seems like there is no workaround sorry. I would recommend getting a graphics tablet or an optical mouse or seeing if reverting back to Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS helps.

Comment: Try this http://askubuntu.com/a/211755/15943

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this solution, it works for me.

http://www.linuxwind.org/html/dell-touchpad-driver-for-ubuntu-13-04.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.