# Issue with AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint touchpad on DELL PRECISION M6700

Tags: touchpad

My touchpad is EXTREMELY choppy.  I'm not sure if this is a driver issue or what.  I tried following the steps in answer:
[Alps Touchpad on Dell: how do I install the DKMS driver to enable multitouch?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154770/alps-touchpad-on-dell-how-do-i-install-the-dkms-driver-to-enable-multitouch)

But all of the links are out-dated/do not work, not to mention a lot of the commands sound like complete german to a new linux user.  I've been googling on this issue for 3 hours to no avail. I'm completely stuck at this point and of ideas so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to report a bug against Ubuntu. They are planning to fix the issue by 14.04, so you may be lucky that your issue will get solved by then. Report your issue, follow the instructions and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

To get touchpad properties on M6700, enter this:

```
xinput list-props "AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad" | grep -i finger
```

To set touchpad properties to be a bit less touchy than default, I entered this:

```
xinput set-prop "AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad" "Synaptics Finger" 15, 20, 128
```