# TouchPad on Dell E7470 not working as expected on 16.04

Tags: drivers, 16.04, mouse, touchpad, dell

As described in a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/1590590), the TouchPad in the Dell Latitude E7470 cannot be configured (there are no dedicated options for the TouchPad available), and while two-finger scrolling works fine, the middle mouse button, for example, cannot be used for scrolling together with the track point.

How can this situation be resolved, i.e., what drivers help in this situation?

`xinput`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ DELL Wireless hotkeys                     id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix the touchpad issue on Dell E7470, update it to BIOS Version: 1.18.5 ,1.18.5 
Release Date: 06 Feb 2018 File Name: Latitude_E7x70_1.18.5.exe.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the Latitude E7470 touchpad driver sucks. At least, you can set up mid button scrolling as I confirmed at [Settings for Glidepoint touchpad/trackpoint on Dell Latitude](https://askubuntu.com/questions/428602/settings-for-glidepoint-touchpad-trackpoint-on-dell-latitude/830141#830141).